# Using LibCurlNet to make an authenticated http get request from json rest API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, curl, restful-authentication

### cURL requests, webrequest or any method of consumption:

Little yellow birds are flying around my head as I have never used cURL with asp.net; what I am trying to achieve (hopefully it is also sensible) is to use the **LibCurlNet dlls** in order to make a simple get request to [**Police API**](http://www.police.uk/api/docs/authentication/) using my given username and password.

Using this every request must include your API username & password. Example with Curl:

```
curl -u username:password http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/forces
```

The API is implemented as a standard JSON REST web service using HTTP GET requests.

**I am hoping to have a c# class like a webmethod in order to make ajax call to using jquery to retrieve the information from API.**

I know how to make web methods but I don't know how to combine it with LibCurlNet.

The only reason I am blabbering about LibCurlNet is not that I am in love with it, so if you think I should be using a different method to consume the data from this API please let do so.

*Please let me know if I can provide anything to make this more clear.*

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public const String LocalCrime = http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/leicestershire/C01/crime";

[WebMethod(true)]
public static String request()
{
    // Initialize the WebRequest.
    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(LocalCrime);

    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    // Return the response. 
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StringBuilder _Content = new StringBuilder();
    using (StreamReader _Reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        _Content.Append(_Reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    // Code to use the WebResponse goes here.

    // Close the response to free resources.
    myResponse.Close();
    return _Content.ToString();
}
```

with script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "police/crimerequest.aspx/request",
    dataType: "json",
    // success: insertCallback 
    success: function (data) {
        $('#requestResult').append(data.d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Sorry there was an error, try again!');
        return false;
    }
});
```